# select-string to find matches, and use these results to rename/copy files

Tags: powershell

```
$inputfile = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\temp\*.xml
foreach ($name in $inputfile)
    {
        $rg = Get-Content -Path $name | Select-String -Pattern "(?<=\#\s)(\d{10})" | Select-Object {$_.matches.groups[0].Value} | select -first 1
        $file = Get-Content -Path $name | Select-String -Pattern "[0-9].pdf" | Select-Object {$_.matches.groups[0].Value} | select -first 1  
        Copy-Item "C:\temp\$file" -Destination "C:\temp\output\$rg.pdf"
    }
```

I am reading XML files and use select-string to find the matches I want.
The result of $rg is 0123456789
The result of $file is 1.pdf

```
$_.matches.groups[0].Value
--------------------------
0123456789                
1.pdf
```

As the last step, I'd like to copy 1.pdf to a subdirectory and rename it to 0123456789.pdf

But the files are not copied with no error given. I could imagine that I would need to store the results in an array and should then be able to iterate through it, so there is always a dataset that has one $rg associated to one $file. Other than that, I am out of ideas. I am new to powershell and scripting in general and I guess it is something basic I am missing.

/edit:
As instructed by JosefZ, the copy-item cmdlet was changed, and now delivers the desired result:

```
Copy-Item -Path "C:\temp\$file.'matches.groups[0].value')" -Destination (New-Item -Name "$($rg.'$_.matches.groups[0].Value').pdf" -ItemType file -Path "C:\temp\output\")
```

This will copy the file 1.pdf in this example to 0123456789.pdf

Comment: Are you sure your values of $rg and $file are what you say they are?

Comment: also make sure the "C:\Temp\output" path exists. Copy-Item will not make the folder structure for you.

Comment: Thank you Patrick. The second code block is the output of $rg and $file, and the path exists. I had an output once but changed the code since. However, it didn't create files but directories, and the dir names where the full line of text select-string found, not the  part I boiled the strings down to at the end of each pipe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parsing XML using a regex isn't a good idea, in full generality…
You should parse an XML document using proper tools, e.g. [`Select-Xml` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-xml).

However, if you insist upon chosen approach, have in mind the following (and similarly for the `$file` variable):

```
"C:\temp\output\$rg.pdf"
```

> ```
> C:\temp\output\@{$_.matches.groups[0].Value=0123456789}.pdf
> ```

Try

```
"C:\temp\output\$($rg.'$_.matches.groups[0].Value').pdf"
```

> ```
> C:\temp\output\0123456789.pdf
> ```

Comment: Thank you, this works (basically). After those changes, the script succesfully copied items, but the new items were folders once again. So either copy-item would like to have path and (file)name separated, or the current path ("C:\temp\output\$($rg.'$_.matches.groups[0].Value').pdf") stops at "output\" and doesn't interpret our variable, so it actually copies the folder. However, I think I am on track now and should be able to fix it.

I absolutely agree that select-xml would be preferred, but the input xml documents I received were nowhere near valid xml, no valid nodes to work with.

Comment: @marvis Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76046884/edit) to improve your [mcve]. In particular, share `Get-Item "C:\temp\$($file.'$_.matches.groups[0].Value')"`